# In any program doesn't 100% statement coverage imply 100 % branch coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage

While solving MCQs for a practice test I came across this statement - "In any program 100% statement coverage implies 100 % branch coverage" and it is termed as incorrect. I think its a correct statement because if we cover all the statements then it means we also cover all the paths and hence all the branches. Could someone please shed more light on this one?

Comment: For a basic introduction into several test metrics, see [Code Coverage Tutorial: Branch, Statement & Decision Testing](https://www.guru99.com/code-coverage.html "Code Coverage Tutorial: Branch, Statement &amp; Decision Testing").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
...
if (SomeCondition) DoSomething();
...
```

If `SomeCondition` is always true, you can have 100% statement coverage (`SomeCondition` and `DoSomething()` will be covered), but you never exercise the case when the condition is false, when you skip `DoSomething()`.

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full for the above answer, probably with people providing alternative links. Here's my suggestion: https://www.guru99.com/code-coverage.html

Comment: The code example explicitly shows an empty else branch. So whether we can get any benefit from tests with `SomeCondition` set to `false` is completely hidden.

Comment: I don't think that it's necessary for `someCondition` to be always true here; the absence of an `else` block is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you cover every statement doesnt mean that you covered every branch the program could have taken.

you have to look at every possible branch, not just the statements inside every branch.

Comment: I'm sorry but its not clear me to yet. For example suppose we have a program with a simple switch-case and we have 10 cases, and if we cover all those 10 cases it means we have covered all the possible branches too, right?

Comment: @BuddhaSaadhu: Wrong.  I've only really just learned this.  With your switch statement there is also the 11th case where the switch value does not match any of the cases.

Comment: I think you should add to your answer that not jumping into a control-statement's body means branching, too, otherwise this answer seems confusing to the unknowing.

Answer (score 3):

For a test set to achieve 100% branch coverage, every branching point in the code must have been taken in each direction, at least once.

The archetypical example, showing that 100% statement coverage does not imply 100% branch coverage,  was already given by Alexey Frunze. It is a consequence of the fact that (at least in the majority of programming languages) it is possible to have branches that do not involve statements (such a branch basically skips the statements in the other branch).

The reason for wanting 100% branch coverage, rather than just 100% statement coverage, is that your tests must also show that skipping some statements works as expected.

My main reason for providing this answer is to point out that the converse, viz. "100% branch coverage implies 100% statement coverage" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Below example,   a = true will cover 100% of statements, but fails to test the branch where a division by zero fault is possible.

```
int fun(bool a){
  int x = 0;
  if (a) x =1;
  return 100/x;
}
```

Comment: You give a very good example here. But the statement should be rephrased. When you ask in what sense, try to ask who/what is *`covering`* in the given text. In my opinion, a single test that calls the function with the argument `true` to prove that the result is `100` provides 100% statement coverage for the function `fun`.